# Query web resource with curl on wamp

Tags: php, wampserver

```
$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, "https://duckduckgo.com/");
curl_exec($connection);
curl_close($connection);
```

This part of code return null on my wamp server. Work only if CURLOPT_URL is localhost resource. How to make curl work for web sites? file_get_contents() work well.

Comment: [`curl_error($connection)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) What does that tell you. OR Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I really recommend you to see this first https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/4906348